# What is the error in following MPI program to calculate area under curve by rectangles' area summation approach

Tags: c, mpi

I am calculating the value of pi(3.14) by finding area under the curve 4/1+(x*x) from limits 0 to 1. Following is MPI program in C for doing so.

However, when there is one process, it gives correct value. If I give more than one process then only process having rank 0 gives some value while other processes give 0.0 as their locally computed value

What error is there in the following code ?

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_NAME 80 
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{


    MPI_INIT(&argc,&argv);
    int rank,nprocs,len;
    double i=0.0;
    double n=1000000000.0;
    double PI25DT =3.141592653589793238462643;
    double mypi,pi,step,sum,x;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    double start_time,end_time,computation_time;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
   MPI_Get_processor_name(name,&len);   
   start_time=MPI_Wtime();

    sum=0.0;
    step=1.0/(double)n;

    x=0.0;
    x=(double)rank*(n/nprocs);
    x=x+step;
    double temp=x;
    for(i=temp;i<(temp+(n/nprocs));i=i+1.0)
    {

       sum+=step*(4.0/(1.0+(double)(x*x)));
       x=x+step;    
     }


    mypi=sum;
    printf("\nProcessor: %d Name: %s Sum: %.16f \n",rank,name,mypi);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&mypi,&pi,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank==0)
    {
    printf("\nValue of Pi is %.16f approximately .Error is %.16f \n",pi,fabs(pi-PI25DT));
    end_time=MPI_Wtime();
    computation_time=end_time-start_time;
    printf("\nComputation time is: %f seconds.\n",computation_time);
    }
   MPI_Finalize();
  }
```

Output of above code for one process and more than one process is as:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLblG.png)

Comment: "I am not getting correct pi value as answer. " --> What answer does code produce?

Comment: `n/nprocs` is integer division.  Is that correct for `x=rank*(n/nprocs);`?

Comment: This code is working fine for one process. If I give nprocs>1, then its giving wrong value

Comment: The other processes give 0.0 because of `n`, hence `x`. Here, `sum+=step*(4.0/(1.0+(double)(x*x)));` `x*x` is a huge number compared to `4`. For master, `x` starts from zero. That's why you get correct answer for uniprocess.

Answer (score 0):

The entire logic in your code seems flawed - you have confused integers and doubles in your "for" loop which means the loop limits are all wrong.

The easiest way to debug simple programs is just to print to the screen - I'm eternally surprised by how reticent people are to just get their program to tell them what it's actually doing.

If I set n=5.0 and change the loop to:

```
x=x+step;
printf("rank %d has x = %lf\n", rank, x);
```

then on 2 processes I get:

```
rank 0 has x = 0.400000
rank 0 has x = 0.600000
rank 0 has x = 0.800000

Processor: 0 Name: starless Sum: 2.0471212357622095 

Value of Pi is 2.3040395511642187 approximately .Error is 0.8375531024255745 

Computation time is: 0.000067 seconds.
rank 1 has x = 2.900000
rank 1 has x = 3.100000
rank 1 has x = 3.300000

Processor: 1 Name: starless Sum: 0.2569183154020093
```

showing the loop limits are wrong.

I don't think they're even correct on a single process:

```
rank 0 has x = 0.400000
rank 0 has x = 0.600000
rank 0 has x = 0.800000
rank 0 has x = 1.000000
rank 0 has x = 1.200000
```

Surely the integral is between 0.0 and 1.0?

Regards,

David